# Question on proving function is $C^\infty(\left]0,\infty\right[)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

As a part of my question I am attempting to prove that $f \in C^\infty( 
 \left] 0,\infty \right[)$ whereby $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x}}, x>0$.

How do I go about doing this.

My idea ist to look at $g(x)=\exp(x)$ and $h(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$ and prove that they're both $\in C^\infty(\left]0,\infty\right[)$ and using the chain rule show that $f$ is infinitely differentiable.

However, how would I even prove that? Surely, finding the nth derivative using induction is by no means proving differentiability?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Composition of smooth functions is smooth. $e^x$ and $-1/x$ are smooth on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: How do I prove that?

Comment: Transfinite induction?

Comment: Clearer. $f\circ g$ is differentiable since $f$ and $g$ are differentiable. Suppose that $f\circ g$ has derivatives up to order $n$ whenever $f,g$ are smooth functions. Then $(f\circ g)'=f'\circ g\cdot g'$. Since $g'$ is smooth it has derivatives up to order $n$, since $f'$ and $g$ are smooth, then $f'\circ g$ also has derivative up to order $n$. Therefore, $f'\circ g\cdot g'$  has derivative up to order $n$. Hence $f\circ g$ has derivative up to order $n+1$ too. Therefore, when $f,g$ are smooth, $f\circ g$ has derivatives of all orders.

Comment: Above I used that if $f,g$ has derivatives up to order $n$, then the product $f\cdot g$ has derivatives up to order $n$. This is the same inductive business. $(f\cdot g)'=f'\cdot g+f\cdot g'$. Each $f'\cdot g$ and $f\cdot g'$ has derivatives up to order $n-1$. Therefore, their sum has derivatives up to order $n-1$.

Comment: I'd say that $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(e^x) = e^x$ and $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(-\frac{1}{x}) = (-1)^{n+1}\cdot n! \cdot x^{-n-1}$ and therefore they are both infinitely differentiable and that composition of $C^\infty$ function results in a $C^\infty$ function